# Global Regex Substitution with Unique Arbitrary Values

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I have one huge HTML files with many links i.e. `<a href="...">`. I need to substitute each `href` with a unique arbitrary value. So, after substitution the first link will be `<a href="http://link1">`, second link `<a href="http://link2">`, and so on.

Can we do this using a regex? Or, do I need to write a small script to scan over the file? Ideally, the solution will be a Perl or bash script (not something proprietary).

Thanks.

Comment: It’s probably best to write a little script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl is probably your best bet, but I wouldn't try to do it in one regex (might not even be possible). I think this is as short as you can make the script while still making it readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$link = 1;
while(<>) {
    $link++ while( s/href="(?!link\d)[^"]*"/href="link$link"/ );
    print;
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
./thatScript.pl inputFile.html > newInputFile.html
```

It will examine each line of input, and for each `href="..."` it finds, replaces it with a numbered link and increments the link number. There is also a negative lookahead to avoid replacing the same `href` continuously.

**EDIT:** Just for the hell of it, here's how you would compress the above into a single line of bash:

```
perl -pe '$link++ while( s/href="(?!link\d)[^"]*"/href="link$link"/ )' inFile.html > outFile.html
```

This makes use of Perl's amazing `-p` flag, as explained [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-one/).

Answer (score 1):

I definitely don't recommend this (tchrist is right, of course, it should be a script) but it does have the virtue of being terse and fulfilling the literal requirements in a deterministic/repeatable way without needing to save state/mapping.

```
perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -MXML::LibXML -le '$d = XML::LibXML->load_html( location => shift || die "need location" ); for $a ( $d->findnodes("//\@href") ) { $a->setValue( md5_hex $a->value ) }; print $d->serialize' targeted.html
```

- [Digest::MD5](http://metacpan.org/module/Digest%3a%3aMD5)
- [XML::LibXML](http://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML)

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
perl -pe 's{(href=")[^"]+}{$1 . "http://link" . ++$count}ge' filename > newfile
```